# How to take out unique ids in array of objects and return them by earliest date? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array with objects.  I want my array to return the objects with unique ids and to select the earliest date.

so in this case it would be [{id:1, date: Jan 12}, {id:2, date:Feb 8}, {id:3, date: Feb 8}]

```js
var array = [{id: 1, date: Jan 12 2021 08:00:00 AM}, {id: 2, date: Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM}, {id: 2, date: Mar 2 2021 08:00:00 AM}, {id: 3, date: Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM}]
```

Edit: forgot to add that the date format is a string formated moment("MM-DD-YYYY");

Here is my code so far:

```js
var withId = array.filter(function (g) { return g.Id != null });

withId = array.filter(function (e) { return moment(e.UtcStart) < moment() && e.DteEndDate != null ? moment(e.DteEndDate) > moment() : true });

withId.sort(function (a, b) { return moment(a.UtcStart) - moment(b.UtcStart) });

var key = 'Id';

var unique = [...new Map(withId.map(x => [x[key], x])).values()];
```

Comment: What data type is the `date` property? Is it a string? If so, exactly what format does it take?

Comment: Oh right.. sorry, yeah the date property is a string. formated moment("MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to get the required result. We loop over each item , creating a map based on `id`. We only replace each entry in the map if the date is earlier than the existing entry at acc[id]:

```js
var array = [{id: 1, date: 'Jan 12 2021 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 2, date: 'Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 2, date: 'Mar 2 2021 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 3, date: 'Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM'}];

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, { id, date }) => { 
    if (!acc[id] || Date.parse(acc[id].date) > Date.parse(date)) acc[id] = { id, date };
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your array based on dates

```js
let array = [{id: 1, date: 'Jan 12 2021 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 2, date: 'Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 2, date: 'Mar 2 2021 08:00:00 AM'}, {id: 3, date: 'Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM'}]
let sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))// sort in reverse because Map takes the last found value of the same key
let twoDeimentionalArray = sortedArray.map(item=>[item.id,item.date])
let map = new Map(twoDeimentionalArray)//To Create a set
```

and work on that.

Also

```js
var array = [
{id: 1, date: 'Jan 12 2021 08:00:00 AM'}, 
{id: 2, date: 'Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM'}, 
{id: 2, date: 'Mar 2 2020 08:00:00 AM'}, 
{id: 3, date: 'Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM'},
{id: 2, date: 'July 8 2022 08:00:00 AM'},
{id: 4, date: 'Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM'}
]
let sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date))).sort((a, b) => (a.id- b.id))

const reducedArray = sortedArray.reduce(function(set,item){
    return (set.length !== 0 && set[set.length-1].id == item.id) ?  set : set.concat(item)
},new Array)
console.log(sortedArray)
console.log(reducedArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the later date of the same id, does that helps?

```
var array = [{id: 1, date: "Jan 12 2021 08:00:00 AM"}, {id: 2, date: "Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM"}, {id: 2, date: "Mar 2 2021 08:00:00 AM"}, {id: 3, date: "Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM"}]
var uniqMap = {};
array.forEach(v => {
    if (!uniqMap[v.id] || (Date.parse(v.date) < Date.parse(uniqMap[v.id]))) {
        uniqMap[v.id] = v;
    }
})
console.log(uniqMap);
// convert map to array
var uniqIds = Object.keys(uniqMap).map((key) => uniqMap[key]);
console.log(uniqMap);

// print result is:
0: {id: 1, date: 'Jan 12 2021 08:00:00 AM'}
1: {id: 2, date: 'Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM'}
2: {id: 3, date: 'Feb 8 2021 08:00:00 AM'}
```